# HOG with cascade or SVM classifier. C++ programe in OpenCV (V2.4.5) ?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, svm

Using an IP camera with PTZ, detecting human in opencv (windows). good article or tutorial to follow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642296/hog-for-detecting-object-opencv

Comment: just google "hog pedestrian detection opencv.

Answer (score 0):

visit https://github.com/DaHoC/trainHOG

it has a tutorial and sample code for detecting humans using  HOG + Svmlight.
You can use the sample code (with some changes :)) in visual studio. (at least you can get an idea)