# how can I use xml file as HOG descriptor instead of DefaultPeopleDetector in python?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to count people in the video with opencv and python

I got an external xml file for HOG descriptor for it.

So I wanna set this file as a descriptor, but I don't know how to do it.

First I tried like below :

'cascade.xml' is customized file.

```
hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor('cascade.xml')
hog.setSVMDetector(cv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector())
```

But it didn't work.

And then I tried another way like below referring to 
[OpenCV HOGDescripter Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28390614/opencv-hogdescripter-python/31042147#31042147) :

```
hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
hog.save("cascade.xml")
```

It didn't work neither.

program didn't emit error, nothing happened.

What should I do?