# Set up size of HOG descriptor output

Tags: opencv

I have code:

```
 import cv2
 hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
 im = cv2.imread(sample)
 h = hog.compute(im)
```

I want to have output is size 30720. Can you teach me. Thanks!

Comment: You need to understand how the size of the descriptor is calculated and change the parameters accordingly. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28390614/opencv-hogdescripter-python) you can check what parameters you can change and how to do so and how to calculate the size