# Error while using HOGDescriptor()

Tags: python, opencv

Code for using HOG (Histogram of Oriented Gradients) is as follows:

```
def get_hog() : 
winSize = (20,20)
blockSize = (8,8)
blockStride = (4,4)
cellSize = (8,8)
numberbins = 9
derivAperture = 1
winSigma = -2.
histogramNormType = 0
L2HysThreshold = 0.4
gCorrection = 1
numberlevels = 66
signedGradient = True

hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor(winSize,blockSize,blockStride,cellSize,numberbins,derivAperture,winSigma,histogramNormType,L2HysThreshold,gCorrection,numberlevels, signedGradient)

return hog
```

I am getting the following error:
"TypeError: HOGDescriptor() takes at most 1 argument (12 given)"

How should I resolve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448628/opencv-version-3-hogdescriptor-takes-at-most-1-argument-5-given)

Comment: First ,your code is not formatted.Second,I.Newton is right.

Comment: I have a problem because I am passing 12 arguments. Could you maybe suggest a solution for this particular case?