# opencv assertion failed error while computing HOG feature of an image in python

Tags: python, opencv

I want to computer HOG feature of an image using opencv hog.compute(image) function in python. But it gave me this error

> "OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= _rowRange.start &&
>   _rowRange.start <= _rowRange.end && _rowRange.end <= m.rows) in Mat, file /home/dipdeb/opencv-3.1.0/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 469
>   *** Error in `python': free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x0000000002b319d0 ***"

here is my code

```
import cv2
hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
im = cv2.imread("35.jpg")
h = hog.compute(im)
```

Comment: It seems that your image is too small. What's its size? Are you loading it correctly?

Comment: thanks for the comment. yes my picture size is too small(12*24 pixels). Actually I want to calculate small size of character in order to compare with other characters for recognition. I think I should increase it's size or is there any other option to do that?

Comment: Or decrease box and cell sizes...

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: You can do that [in the constructor](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/d33/structcv_1_1HOGDescriptor.html#ac0544de0ddd3d644531d2164695364d9). However setting the correct parameters could be quite complex/confusing. Probably is better to just increase the image size.. Sorry for the confusion ;D

Comment: Try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090399/get-hog-image-features-from-opencv-python