# weird behaviour due to opencv code

Tags: opencv, python-3.6

I tried to find the hog features using [Get HOG image features from OpenCV + Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25119903)

but whenever I run the below stub, it causes my user session to log out and when I login back to os, then all the windows are closed.

```
import cv2
img=cv2.imread('Figure_1.png')
print(img.shape)
img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
hog=cv2.HOGDescriptor()
m=hog.compute(img)
print(img.shape)
cv2.imshow('hog',m)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.DestroyAllWindows()
```

Can somebody please tell why I am witnessing this behaviour and any suggestions, if the code is buggy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code has a few bugs.

1. The `cv2.HOGDescriptor()` object **must** be initialized with a few parameters. This is probably one of the reasons the code crashes.
2. It's `cv2.destroyAllWindows()` and not `cv2.DestroyAllWindows()`
3. I'm guessing you want to destroy the image window on a key press. To achieve that, the `cv2.destroyAllWindows()` should be conditioned on the `cv2.waitKey()`
4. Also, you are trying to view the Hog in an image window. This is not the correct way to do it. The scikit-learn package has functions to let you view the HOG. An example of this is [here](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_hog.html).

The corrected code is:

```
import cv2
img=cv2.imread('Figure_1.png')
print(img.shape)
print(img.shape)
winSize = (64,64)
blockSize = (16,16)
blockStride = (8,8)
cellSize = (8,8)
nbins = 9

hog=cv2.HOGDescriptor(winSize,blockSize,blockStride,cellSize,nbins)
m=hog.compute(img)
print(img.shape)
cv2.imshow('hog',img)
if cv2.waitKey() == 27: #27 refers to the Esc key
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```