# compute method of cv2.HOGDescriptor always returns an empty tuple

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python

I am using the code snippet given in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090399/get-hog-image-features-from-opencv-python) to compute HOG feature of a small image patch. However for the code attached herewith, the variable `h`, which is supposed to hold HOG feature values, is returning an empty tuple instead. Can anyone please point me to where am I going wrong in the code?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('newimg.jpg')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_gray = cv2.resize(img_gray,(50,50))

hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
h = hog.compute(img_gray)
print(h)
```

The test image is attached [image: here]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is problem regarding the image size. More specifically image size is smaller as compare to the default window size of hog Descriptor. I recommend resize your image and then use the code snippet attached below.

```
winSize = (32,32)
blockSize = (16,16)
blockStride = (8,8)
cellSize = (8,8)
nbins = 9
hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor(winSize, blockSize, blockStride, cellSize, nbins)
h = hog.compute(img_gray)
print(h)
```