# issue while writing cvGetImage using cvMat

Tags: opencv

I am facing a problem while writing image from cvMat.

This is what I have done.

```
IplImage* low_threshold_mask = cvCreateImage(cvSize(width, height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
CvMat* labelMat = cvCreateMat(low_threshold_mask->height,low_threshold_mask->width,CV_32F);
```

/* I populate elements of labelMat inside a function. Its done like this: cvmSet(labelMat,r,c,label); // where label is of type **long** */

To check the values I dump each pixel value in a text file and also dump the image.

```
IplImage* labelImg;
IplImage imageHeader;
labelImg = cvGetImage(labelMat, &imageHeader);
```

Now when I cross-check pixel intensity with corresponding value in dumped text file, I find mis-match. I feel I have got correct values in text file but wrong ones in image.

Can anyone help in figuring out the mistake?

---

---------------------New addition-------------------

I am still facing the problem. I have uploaded my [programs](https://sites.google.com/site/learningcomputervision/background-subtraction/grimsongmm). I will explain where exactly I am facing the error.

**Libraries** used: Along with openCV, I am using disjoint_sets of boost library.

Basically I am doing **connected component labeling**. 
For debugging purpose, for 20th frame, I have dumped the label info of each pixel both in a)text file as well b) an image with intensity levels same as the final label of the pixels. So i am expecting the values same in both text and image. But that's not happening. And I am unable to figure out why. The text files shows the correct values but not the image. I am checking pixel values of image in Matlab(i had taken care of indices in matlab starts with 1 not 0).

My text files
a) (frame20final.txt) gets populated in GrimsonGMM.cpp/ConCompLabeling().
b) (frame20image.txt) gets populated in main.cpp
My dumped image(frame-ccs.jpg) gets populated in main.cpp.

Both the text files get same values. **So there must be some mistake in writing the image from CvMat.**

Test Video: [person15_walking_d1_uncomp.avi](http://www.nada.kth.se/cvap/actions/)
You can try with any other video also.

Thanks in advance,
Kaushik

Answer (score 1):

I understood why I was getting the error. I was dumping in **.jpg** image which was doing compression. This was resolved when I used .png

Answer (score 0):

Your question its so easy.

You want to work with CvMat and after do operations with CvMat you want to plot your CvMat like it was an image.

You must create imageHeader, something like this.

```
CvMat* mat = cvCreateMatHeader(rows, cols, type);
mat->step = 4 * (mat->cols * CV_ELEM_SIZE1(mat->type) * CV_MAT_CN(mat->type) / 4 + 1);//critical
cvCreateData(mat);
```

In OpenCV 2.0 and below C++ interface it's not really necessary to change from Mat to IplImage.

You can plot your image using `cvShowImage` and if you want to convert into`IplImage` 
just do a easy cast IplImage *img = labelMat;

Comment: But shouldn't cvGetImage also work as explained by rics in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468307/how-to-convert-a-mat-variable-type-in-an-iplimage-variable-type-in-opencv-2-0/2475735#2475735

Comment: Plus in OpenCV 2.0 it gives the error: cannot convert from 'CvMat *' to 'IplImage *'