# Detect coherent neighbors / neighborhood in 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays, neighbours

Im having an arbitrary 2d array and each field has an id and a teamid (here illustrated as colors [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oM4zw.jpg)).

I want for every neighborhood an array with the ids
in it.

A neighborhood consists of fields with neighbors with the same teamid horizontally and vertically (not diagonally)

e.g.: 
This is what i have:

[image: Field]

```
array[0][0] = {id:1,teamId:1} 
array[1][0] = {id:2,teamId:1} 
array[2][0] = {id:3,teamId:0}
array[3][0] = {id:4,teamId:2}
array[4][0] = {id:5,teamId:2}
array[5][0] = {id:6,teamId:0}

array[0][1] = {id:7,teamId:1} 
array[1][1] = {id:8,teamId:1} 
array[2][1] = {id:9,teamId:1}
array[3][1] = {id:10,teamId:2}
array[4][1] = {id:11,teamId:2}
array[5][1] = {id:12,teamId:0}

//and so on..
```

This is what i want:

[image: Field]

```
neighborhood[1] = [1,2,7,8,9,13,14]
neighborhood[2] = [4,5,10,11]
neighborhood[3] = [16,22,23,24,29,30]
neighborhood[4] = [25,31,32,37,38]
neighborhood[5] = [35,41]
```

I am not searching for the images, but for the array

```
neighborhood
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the bottom picture the desired output or do you want small little numbers inside each box? It is a bit unclear as to what you are asking

Comment: thanks, i just edited my post. i hope it is clear now.

Comment: I also dont understand what you are asking. Do you want a visual representation of the teamid on the image?

Comment: I'm still a bit confused... Do you want a method to group together the "neighborhoods"?

Comment: check the answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30694603/detect-coherent-neighbors-neighborhood-in-2d-array/30698982#30698982

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The method for solving this issue is refered as [Connected Component Labelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling)

A  [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465297/connected-component-labelling/14466081#14466081) was asked once before from which i have my solution:

```js
// matrix dimensions
var row_count = 20;
var col_count = 20;
var numOfTeams = 2;

// the input matrix
var m = [];
// the labels, 0 means unlabeled
var label = [];
var source = document.getElementById("source");
for (var i = 0; i < row_count; i++) {
  var row = source.insertRow(0);
  m[i] = [];
  label[i] = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < col_count; j++) {
    //m[i][j] = Math.round(Math.random());
    m[i][j] = getRandomInt(0, numOfTeams + 1);
    label[i][j] = 0;
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.innerHTML = m[i][j];
  }
}

// direction vectors
var dx = [1, 0, -1, 0];
var dy = [0, 1, 0, -1];

function dfs(x, y, current_label, team) {
  if (x < 0 || x == row_count) return; // out of bounds
  if (y < 0 || y == col_count) return; // out of bounds
  if (label[x][y] || team != m[x][y]) return; // already labeled or not marked with 1 in m


  // mark the current cell
  label[x][y] = current_label;

  // recursively mark the neighbors
  for (var direction = 0; direction < 4; ++direction) {
    dfs(x + dx[direction], y + dy[direction], current_label, team);
  }
}


function find_components() {
  var component = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < row_count; ++i) {
    for (var j = 0; j < col_count; ++j) {

      if (!label[i][j] && m[i][j]) dfs(i, j, ++component, m[i][j]);
    }
  }
}

find_components();

var result = document.getElementById("result");


for (var i in label) {
  var string = ""
  var row = result.insertRow(0);
  for (var j in label[i]) {
    string += label[i][j] + " "
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.innerHTML = label[i][j];
  }
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

```css
table tr td {
  min-width: 14px
}
```

```html
<div style="float:left">
  <table id="source"></table>
</div>
<div style="float:right">
  <table id="result"></table>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't this similar to adjacency list:http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-and-its-representations/.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the logic from dots and block games. A block belongs to a player if he has surrounded it with the walls. So, you need for each cell also 4 walls except for the outer cells. To test if a cell is closed you can use 4 class variables:

```
var Block = function() {
  this.isclosed=0;
  this.left=0;
  this.top=0;
  this.right=0;
  this.bottom=0;
  return this;
}

Block.prototype = {
  isClosed : function () {
    if (this.isclosed==true) {
      return false;
    } else if (this.left && this.top && this.right && this.bottom) {
      this.isclosed=true;
      return true;
    } else {
      return this.left && this.top && this.right && this.bottom;
    }
  }
}
```

You can try my implementations of dots and blocks game @ https://dotsgame.codeplex.com/.

Comment: im not exactly sure, whether this solves my problem. since im having neighbors with more than 9 fields

Comment: Can you add a variable player to the class? My idea is to use this if-else statement with all 4 walls.