# Check efficiently if two pixels of an image are connected

Tags: algorithm

Suppose you have an arbitrary black and white image, consider the following ones as an example:

```
...........     ........... 
...........     ........... 
...........     ........... 
.OOO...O...     ........... 
X...O.O.OOY     XOOO...OOOY 
.....O.....     ........... 
...........     ........... 
...........     ........... 
...........     ...........
```

Where `"."` represent black pixels, `"O"`, `"X"`, `"Y"` represent white pixels

The left picture's `X` and `Y` pixels are interconnected between themselves along the path of `O`'s (in terms of [Moore's neighbourhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_neighborhood)). While on the right picture `X` and `Y` pixels are disconnected. By having an arbitrary black and white image, I need highly performant algorithm that will answer the question whether some group of pixels is connected to another group of pixels. I'm pretty sure that there has to be well-developed solution to this problem, since the problem looks common, but I can't seem to find one that would suite me. And by the way I'm aware of [Flood Fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithm but currently I'm not considering it, since it does more job than it is required to answer the initial question.

I would appreciate reference to any info in subject direction,

## P.S.

Just in case you have the answer the original question, maybe you might have answer to the following:

```
...........
...........
...........
.OOO...O...
X...O.O.OOY
.....O.....
..........Z
..........U
..........V
```

It would be also great (but not required) could answer the initial question in the following form:

Pixel `X` is connected to pixel `Y`,

Pixel `X` is not connected to pixel `Z`,

Pixel `X` is not connected to pixel `U`,

Pixel `X` is not connected to pixel `V`,

Thank you in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connected Component Labelling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465297/connected-component-labelling)

Comment: Either Depth-First or Breadth-First Search (as in the linked question) will efficiently answer any of these questions.

Comment: The best algorithm depends on your use-cases. Are you going to have a single image, and then test lots of pairs of pixels on that image? Or is it a different image each time?

Comment: Connected Component Labelling solves my problem in best possible ways, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the problem is pretty common and have a well known performant algorithm which runs in time proportional to the size of the input: `O(n)` (because each vertex have maximum 8 edges). All you need is to pass through the image to create a graph, where each pixel is the vertex and the edge is when 2 vertices are neighbors.

Then having a graph you simply run a [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)/[BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) on your graph, starting with your `X` vertex and stopping if either you reached `Y`, or there is nothing in your frontier.

Notice that here you can also take advantage of heuristics and even use [A* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) (where your heuristics is the [manhattan distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry)).