# Connected Component Labeling

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, connected-components

In OpenCV 3.0 there is a function called [connectedComponent](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gac2718a64ade63475425558aa669a943a).

I know that it takes as input a binary image and returns the labels and the number of connected components, but what algorithm is used internally?

Comment: @Miki In the opencv 3.0 there is a function called connectedComponent and I want know how is made and how works. I know that it takes in input binary image label image which is returned and the connectivity and return the number of connected components, but because I am having to write a report I need to know how it works. Thanks

Comment: Could you try and expand your question.  I am particularly confused by "if someone like it was realized the connectedComponent function provided by the library".  If you can spot an obvious typo in that, fantastic!  If not, you could try and repeat that in other words?  Either way, [edit] your question to fix the problem.

Comment: Right.  I posted my comment while you were posting yours.  As I said: please [edit] the question to include that information.

Comment: @MartinBonner you understand my comment?

Comment: The comment is much better.  Tip: When communicating in a foreign language, prefer to say too much rather than too little, and repeat yourself - it gives other people more chance to guess what you mean.  (Learnt while communicating in German with colleagues.)

Comment: @MartinBonner thanks for this advice, but can you help me or not?

Comment: @user7209199 Your comment is quite clear, while question body is rather weird. It is worth to edit the question using comment contents.

Comment: You have to ask a clear question first.  You must change the question itself to clarify what you want to do.  Comments may get cleaned up.

Comment: I have modified my question. now someone can answer?

Comment: connectedComponents

computes the connected components labeled image of boolean image image with 4 or 8 way connectivity - returns N, the total number of labels [0, N-1] where 0 represents the background label. ltype specifies the output label image type, an important consideration based on the total number of labels or alternatively the total number of pixels in the source image.

C++: int connectedComponents(InputArray image, OutputArray labels, int connectivity=8, int ltype=CV_32S)

Comment: this is the function of which I speak, but I can not find another

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenCV is open source. You can look at the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gac2718a64ade63475425558aa669a943a) and the [source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.0.0/modules/imgproc/src/connectedcomponents.cpp#L182).

You can choose [2 algorithms](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga5ed7784614678adccb699c70fb841075) to perform [connected component lablelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling):

- [CCL_WU](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.2.0-rc/modules/imgproc/src/connectedcomponents.cpp#L186): Based on

  > ["Two Strategies to Speed up Connected Components Algorithms", the SAUF (Scan array union find) variant using decision trees, Kesheng Wu, et al](https://sdm.lbl.gov/~kewu/ps/LBNL-59102.pdf).
- [CCL_GRANA](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.2.0-rc/modules/imgproc/src/connectedcomponents.cpp#L339): Based on

  > ["Optimized  Block-based Connected Components Labeling with Decision Trees", Costantino Grana et al](http://imagelab.ing.unimore.it/imagelab/pubblicazioni/2009TIPlabeling.pdf)

  This works only for 8-connected components.

The default in OpenCV >= 3.2 (`CCL_DEFAULT`) uses Wu's algorithm for 4-connectivity, and Grana's algorithm for 8 connectivity.

**In OpenCV 3.0.0 you use Wu's algorithm for both 4 and 8 connectivity,** while in OpenCV >= 3.2 you can choose one of the 3 options, according to the fields `connectivity` and `ccltype`:

```
       \  connectivity   4    |   8
        \                     |
type     \                    |
                              |
CCL_DEFAULT              Wu   |  Grana
CCL_WU                   Wu   |  Wu
CCL_GRANA                Wu   |  Grana
```

Comment: thanks for the response. You'd have to case documentation available that talks about this algorithm? I tried searching on the Internet, but I find nothing

Comment: You need to search better. I edited the answer with the links to the papers

Comment: another stupid question: having both strategies how do I know what has been used? I'm so sorry for your trouble, but I'm new in the field

Comment: In OpenCV 3.0.0 you use Wu's algorithm for both 4 and 8 connectivity. In OpenCV >= 3.2 You can select which one to use with the fields [`connectivity` and `ccltype`](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaedef8c7340499ca391d459122e51bef5)

Comment: because I used the default options and as connectivity 4, the algorithm used is the right SAUF? sorry again

Answer (score 1):

You can read about connected component labeling algorithms in numerous sources

OpenCV implementation is [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/connectedcomponents.cpp) and contains this clue:

```
 //Based on "Two Strategies to Speed up Connected Components Algorithms", 
 //the SAUF (Scan array union find) variant
 //using decision trees
 //Kesheng Wu, et al
```

[Article](https://sdm.lbl.gov/~kewu/ps/LBNL-59102.pdf)

Comment: thanks for the response. You'd have to case documentation available that talks about this algorithm? I tried searching on the Internet, but I find nothing

Comment: Added link to the article. It was easy googlable

Comment: another stupid question: having both strategies how do I know what has been used? I'm so sorry for your trouble, but I'm new in the field

Comment: I don't know. Source is 80 kB long :)