# Get n largest regions from binary image

Tags: python, algorithm, image-processing, signal-processing

I have given a large binary image  (every pixel is either 1 or 0).

I know that in that image there are multiple regions (a region is defined as a set of neighboring 1s which are enclosed by 0s).

The goal is to find the largest (in terms of pixel-count or enclosed area, both would work out for me for now)

My current planned approach is to:

- start an array of  array of coordinates of the 1s (or 0s, whatever represents a 'hit')
- until no more steps can be made:

  - for the current region (which is a set of coordinates) do:
  - see if any region interfaces with the current region, if yes add them togther, if no continue with the next iteration

My question is: is there a more efficient way of doing this, and are there already tested (bonus points for parallel or GPU-accelerated) implementations out there (in any of the big libraries) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use connected component analysis (a.k.a. labeling). It is more or less what you suggest to do, but there are extremely efficient algorithms out there. Answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14465297/7328782) explain some of the algorithms. See also [connected-components](/questions/tagged/connected-components).

[This library](https://github.com/prittt/YACCLAB) collects different efficient algorithms and compares them.

From within Python, you probably want to use OpenCV. [`cv.connectedComponentsWithStats`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga107a78bf7cd25dec05fb4dfc5c9e765f) does connected component analysis and outputs statistics, among other things the area for each connected component.

With regards to your suggestion: using coordinates of pixels rather than the original image matrix directly is highly inefficient: looking for neighbor pixels in an image is trivial, looking for the same in a list of coordinates requires expensive searchers.

Comment: thanks for the answer, regarding your last comment, thanks for pointing that out, your proposal makes more sense

Answer (score 3):

You could [Flood Fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) every region with an unique ID, mapping the ID to the size of the region.

Comment: now that you mention it, my algorithm is basically the flood fill algorithm, thanks for bringing up the term